# How to pattern-match elements using CSS selectors which EITHER starts with "a" OR ends with "b"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have an HTML code as following:

```
    <div>
     <input id = "adhf" class ="gr"></input>
     <form id = "bkgfsd" class ="fh"></form>
     <input id = "adsada" class ="fr"></input>
    </div>
```

Now I want to do a pattern matching using CSS selectors so that I can grep elements which EITHER have id beginning with "a" or have class ending with "r".

I know ^ is used to pattern match elements beginning with something and $ is used to pattern match elements ending with something, but how can i create a union set of the two?

What will the exact pattern match CSS selector be in this case?

Comment: A selector can have multiple patterns separated by commas, and the overall selector matches any of the patterns.

Comment: Also note that using attribute selectors (`[foo=bar]`) with the `class` attribute is fragile and bug-prone. Elements can have multiple classes, and there's no meaning to the order of classes in the attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't make any pattern for both conditions since are "or" just use both selectors separeted by a `,`-comma, something like:

```css
div > [id^="a"],
div > [class$="r"] {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="and" class="g" placeholder="Target by ID"></input>
  <form id="other" class="fh">Not Target</form>
  <input id="be" class="fr" placeholder="Target by class"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use special attribute selectors like `[id^=a]` id begins with a, or `[class$=r]` class ends with r, and combine them with the comma so:

`[id^=a], [class$=r] { /* styles here */ }`

Comment: Thank you for your response